# How do I use HTML within PHP specifically wrapping output with DIV tags?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, flexbox

I'm gonna post what I've done so far, and full disclosure I'm not at all versed in PHP.

I trying to add DIVS to help me create a layout structure for the PHP output. It appears on the page for the most part, but I'm having difficulty getting some flexbox styling to work.

I'm guessing this is because I'm wrapping HTML around PHP in the wrong places.

[image: My concept layout]

```
<?php if ( have_rows( 'category_listing' ) ) : ?>

<div class="category-container">

    <?php while ( have_rows( 'category_listing' ) ) : the_row(); ?>

    <div class="category-wrapper">

        <div class="category-title">

        <h3><?php the_sub_field( 'category_title' ); ?></h3>

        </div>

        <div class="columns-2">

            <div class="category-icon">

            <?php $icon = get_sub_field( 'icon' ); ?>
            <?php if ( $icon ) { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $icon['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $icon['alt']; ?>" />
            <?php } ?>

            </div>

            <div class="category-item-list">

            <?php if ( have_rows( 'item_list' ) ) : ?>
            <ul class="category-list">

                <?php while ( have_rows( 'item_list' ) ) : the_row(); ?>



                <li>
                    <?php the_sub_field( 'item' ); ?>
                </li>


                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

        <?php else : ?>
            <?php // no rows found ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php // no rows found ?>

</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you please add more details as to how you want the content to look like, i mean you can put the html markup. As it's flexbox related style issue please also provide the css styles you are using; without which it will be hard to know what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the validated PHP code to use. In the PHP code you provided the conditions like `if` & `while` and the `div` inside them where not closing in proper order.

```php
<?php if (have_rows('category_listing')): ?>
  <div class="category-container">
  <?php while (have_rows('category_listing')): the_row(); ?>
    <div class="category-wrapper">
      <div class="category-title">
        <h3><?php the_sub_field('category_title'); ?></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="columns-2">
        <div class="category-icon">
          <?php $icon = get_sub_field('icon'); ?>
          <?php if ($icon): ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $icon['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $icon['alt']; ?>" />
          <?php else: ?>
            <?php /* icon not found */ ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="category-item-list">
          <?php if (have_rows('item_list')): ?>
            <ul class="category-list">
            <?php while (have_rows('item_list')): the_row(); ?>
              <li>
                <?php the_sub_field('item'); ?>
              </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
          <?php else: ?>
            <?php /* no rows found */ ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div>
<?php else: ?>
  <?php /* no rows found */ ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Looking at the designs, it appears that inside the `category-wrapper` the `category-title` should align center over the un-ordered list.

Let's say if we keep the PHP code, that you shared in the question, as constant factor and do not make any changes in it. Instead manage the design requirement using `css` then, the styles used in the stack snippet below should serve your purpose.

You can refine the styles further. I have used the class names provided in the question and assumed the styles based on designs.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.category-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: red;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 600px;
}

.category-wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.category-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

.columns-2 {
  display: flex;
}

.category-icon {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
}

.category-icon img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.category-item-list {
  width: 70%;
}

.category-list {
  column-count: 2;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.category-list li {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-container">

  <div class="category-wrapper">
    <div class="category-title">
      Category Title 1
    </div>
    <div class="columns-2">
      <div class="category-icon">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/FF0000/FFFFFF" />
      </div>
      <div class="category-item-list">
        <ul class="category-list">
          <li>item verylonglengthword</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="category-wrapper">
    <div class="category-title">
      Category Title 2
    </div>
    <div class="columns-2">
      <div class="category-icon">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/FF0000/FFFFFF" />
      </div>
      <div class="category-item-list">
        <ul class="category-list">
          <li>item verylonglengthword</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="category-wrapper">
    <div class="category-title">
      Category Title 3
    </div>
    <div class="columns-2">
      <div class="category-icon">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/FF0000/FFFFFF" />
      </div>
      <div class="category-item-list">
        <ul class="category-list">
          <li>item verylonglengthword</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="category-wrapper">
    <div class="category-title">
      Category Title 4
    </div>
    <div class="columns-2">
      <div class="category-icon">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/FF0000/FFFFFF" />
      </div>
      <div class="category-item-list">
        <ul class="category-list">
          <li>item verylonglengthword</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
          <li>item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The CSS part was very useful, thank you so much. However I really needed help getting the HTML tags (DIVs, UL, etc.) correctly around the PHP. I believe I got most of it done with trial and error, just hoping you or anyone can check it over and advise if I made any mistakes.

Please see my original post I updated to reflect the new code.

Comment: THANK YOU for your patience! Again I apologize for wasting your time trying to answer my ambiguous questions.

Answer (score 0):

I use Bootstrap for this. The following code, wil not run on code snippet, but you can copy and paste somewhere php is running

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
 <?php
  //SHOULD BE A MATRIX, SAME NUMBER OF COLUMNS
  $cars = array
                      (
                      array("Volvo",22,18),
                      array("BMW",15,13),
                      array("Saab",5,2),
                      array("Land Rover",17,15),
                      array("Ferrari",17,15)
                      );
            $tanks = array
                      (
                      array("Hellcat",220,180),
                      array("Tiger",150,130),
                      array("ISU",500,200),
                      array("Cromwell",170,150)
                      );
            $fruits = array
                      (
                      array("Apple",22,18),
                      array("Banana",15,13),
                      array("Watermelon",5,2),
                      );
            $colors = array
                      (
                      array("Black",2,8),
                      array("White",1,3),
                      array("Blue",5,0),
                      array("Green",7,1),
                      array("Yellow",5,0)
                      );
                      
   try {
       //If questions about css verify how Bootstrap 3 works
       print '<div class="container">';
           print '<div class="row">';
       
               //FOR CARS
            print '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">';
            for($x=0;$x<count($cars);$x++){
                for($y=0;$y<count($cars[$x]);$y++){
                    print "<p>".$cars[$x][$y]."</p>";
                }
            }
            print '</div>';
            
            //FOR TANKS
            print '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">';
            for($x=0;$x<count($tanks);$x++){
                for($y=0;$y<count($tanks[$x]);$y++){
                    print "<p>".$tanks[$x][$y]."</p>";
                }
            }
            print '</div>';
        print '</div>';
       print '</div>';
       
       
        //If questions about css verify how Bootstrap 3 works
       print '<div class="container">';
           print '<div class="row">';
            
            //FOR FRUITS
            print '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">';
            for($x=0;$x<count($fruits);$x++){
                for($y=0;$y<count($fruits[$x]);$y++){
                    print "<p>".$fruits[$x][$y]."</p>";
                }
            }
            print '</div>';
            
            //FOR COLORS
            print '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">';
            for($x=0;$x<count($colors);$x++){
                for($y=0;$y<count($colors[$x]);$y++){
                    print "<p>".$colors[$x][$y]."</p>";
                }
            }
            print '</div>';
        print '</div>';
       print '</div>';
   }
   catch(Exception $e) {
                echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
            }
  ?>

</body>

</html>
```

I Hope this can help you

Comment: Thanks for your time! However I'm using WordPress and ACF (advanced custom fields), that's where the php came from. Was really hoping someone could use my code and the illustration to provide an answer.